# Cannot get IIS URL Rewrite/HTTP Redirect to work on Intranet Web Application

Tags: iis

I am trying to get a working web application that is accessible by typing in a browser "servername/appname" to be accessed with "servername/differentnameforapp". I've configured a New Site in IIS for this "differentnameforapp" and set an Inbound rule with the redirect URL to our Webserver's internal IP address. When I type in the new pattern in a web browser, it goes to the main IIS landing page instead. The "appname" appears as a sub-folder in our Default Web Site in IIS. I added a DNS CNAME for this "differentnameforapp" to point to the IP of our server. Still just lands on the main IIS page.

Comment: Talk to your network administrator and learn what DNS can and cannot do first, as " added a DNS CNAME for this "differentnameforapp" to point to the IP of our server" is a wrong step. IIS site bindings also have their own rules, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html so you shouldn't create a new site. On your old site, add an inbound rule to rewrite everything at `differentnameforapp` to `appname` and that's enough.

Comment: The DNS recommendation was per my supervisor. I am a complete noob to IIS. To clarify, I need to set up a URL Rewrite rule on the existing application beneath  where the Rewrite URL is "ServerName\Sites\Default Web Site\appname"? Doing so lands me at the main IIS page when I do so. Is there a specific format to do this? The rule I am entering is "http://servername/appname" and this still lands me on the IIS default page. Thank you very much for responding so quickly to my question.

Comment: You can refer to this link about rewrite url: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module).